# Read email body text and put each line in some different variable

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import imaplib
import re
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
mail.login("****iot@gmail.com","*****iot")
while True:
    mail.select("inbox")
    status, response = mail.search(None,'(SUBJECT "Example")')
    unread_msg_nums = response[0].split()
    data = []
    for e_id in unread_msg_nums:
        _, response = mail.fetch(e_id, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
        data.append(response[0][1].decode("utf-8"))   
        str1 = ''.join(map(str,data))
        #a = int(re.search(r"\d+",str1).group())        
        print(str1)   
    #for e_id in unread_msg_nums:
        #mail.store(e_id, '+FLAGS', '\Seen')
```

When I **print str1 i have this:

```
Temperature:time,5
Lux:time,6
Distance:time,3
```

This is the text from email message and it's ok. It's configuration message for raspberry pi to do some things.
For temperature , lux and Distance i can set  1-10 number(minutes) for each of them, and that numbers represent time for example during which time something will happen in loop. This is all on the side of email message. How to put each line i some different variable, and check them later?

```
**For example**
string1= first line of message #Temperature:time,5
string2= second line of message #Lux:time,6
string3= third line of message #Distance:time,3
```

This is not fix, first line may be Lux, or may be Distance etc..

Comment: Why not just use a list and append each line to it? You could then iterate through them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A job for regular expressions, really (this approach uses a dict comprehension):

```
import re

string = """
Temperature:time,5
Lux:time,6
Distance:time,3
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''^(?P<key>\w+):\s*(?P<value>.+)$''', re.MULTILINE)
cmds = {m.group('key'): m.group('value') for m in rx.finditer(string)}
print(cmds)
# {'Lux': 'time,6', 'Distance': 'time,3', 'Temperature': 'time,5'}
```

The order in which your commands occur does not matter but they need to be unique (otherwise they will get overwritten by the next match). Afterwards, you can get your values with eg. `cmds['Lux']`